# Preventing memory leaks in a multi-threaded daemon process that uses OpenSSL

Tags: c, multithreading, openssl

My application (a multi-threaded daemon process) extensively uses OpenSSL functions including SSL_Read, SSL_Write, generation and verification of of SSL Certificates, etc.
It is currently linked to OpenSSL 1.0.2xx
The application provides a network service, listens to accept connections, and also creates connections to remote peers.

One typical problem I have been facing is constant rise in memory utilization.
Googling, I realized the cardinal need to call ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL) before a thread exits.
I also realized the need to call ERR_clear_error() intermittently.

**I however continue to notice occurance of a spike everytime the application creates over 1024 concurrent threads.**

The code below is my implementation of whatever I have learnt so far.
SSL_thread_setup() is basically an adaption of examples in OpenSSL wiki, I am just calling for initialization of all relevant things with a single call.
SSL_pthreads_locking_callback() is as per the example in the OpenSSL package.
SSL_Mem_clean() is sort of an intermediate ssl error queue related memory flusher.
SSL_Threads_clean() is to properly cleanup a thread before it exits, to prevent any memory leaks.

```
#if 0
/*
Actual code to handle initialization of OpenSSL, in a multi-threaded daemon application
*/
#endif

#ifdef __FD_SETSIZE
#undef __FD_SETSIZE
#endif

#ifdef IS_64BIT
#define __FD_SETSIZE 65472
#else
#define __FD_SETSIZE 8192
#endif

#ifndef FD_SETSIZE
#define FD_SETSIZE __FD_SETSIZE
#endif

pthread_mutex_t _ssl_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t *lock_cs;
long *lock_count;

/*
Initialize OpenSSL libraries and setup for multi-threading
*/
void SSL_thread_setup(void)
{
    int i;

    int x = -1;
    char buf[1024] = "";

    lock_cs=(pthread_mutex_t *)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    lock_count=(long *)OPENSSL_malloc(CRYPTO_num_locks() * sizeof(long));

    for (i=0; i<CRYPTO_num_locks(); i++) {
            lock_count[i]=0;
            pthread_mutex_init(&(lock_cs[i]),NULL);
    }

    CRYPTO_set_id_callback((unsigned long (*)())SSL_pthreads_thread_id);
    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)(int, int, const char *, int)) SSL_pthreads_locking_callback);

    for (x = 0; x < sizeof(buf); x++)
        buf[x] = rand() % 255;

    RAND_seed(buf, sizeof(buf));

    SSL_load_error_strings ();
    SSL_library_init ();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms ();
    OPENSSL_config (NULL);
}

void SSL_pthreads_locking_callback(int mode, int type, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(lock_cs[type]));
        lock_count[type]++;
    } else
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(lock_cs[type]));
}

unsigned long SSL_pthreads_thread_id(void)
{
    return (unsigned long)pthread_self();   
}

/*
Intermediate SSL error queue cleaner
*/
void SSL_Mem_clean()
{
    ERR_clear_error();
    ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);
//  ERR_free_strings(); // crashes
}

/*
Prevent typical "memory leaks" due to multi-threading
*/
void SSL_Threads_clean()
{
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_ENGINE
//              ENGINE_cleanup();
#endif
        ERR_free_strings();
        ERR_clear_error();
        ERR_remove_thread_state(NULL);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&_ssl_lock);
        FIPS_mode_set(0);// good
//      ENGINE_cleanup(); // crashes

//      EVP_cleanup(); // This causes crashes
//      CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data(); // This causes crashes
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_ssl_lock);       
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
#if 0
The dummy code below just exemplifies the usage of:
    SSL_thread_setup()
    SSL_Mem_clean()
    SSL_Threads_clean()
#endif

/*
Generic main of a daemon process, that may spawn multiple threads
*/
int main ()
{
    /* do any pre-forking activity */

    /* setup the signal handlers */
    s_signal_setup();

    SSL_thread_setup(); 

    /* initialize threads array */  
    threads_init();

    fpid = fork();

    switch (fpid) {
    case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "first fork: failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        break;
    case 0:
        chdir("/");
        setsid();
        umask(0);

        fprintf(stdout, "%s:%d fork: \n", __FUNCTION__ , __LINE__ );

        fpid = fork();

        switch (fpid) {
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "second fork: failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        case 0:
            umask(022);
            fix_gid();
            fix_uid();

            umask(027);
            /* call the main purpose of the application */
            mainloop();
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
Called when a thread exits to ensure cleaning to prevent any memory leaks
*/
void thread_release ()
{
    SSL_Threads_clean();
    pthread_exit(0);
}


/*
The actual process of the application
*/
void mainloop ()
{
    void *data_structure;

    while (1) {

        data_structure = get_new_data();

        process_new_data(data_structure);       
    }
}

/*
call to process data in a thread
*/
void process_new_data(void *data_structure)
{
    if (!found_unused_idle_thread (data_structure) ) {

        create_a_detatched_thread((void *) threaded_worker_function, data_structure);
    }

    SSL_Mem_clean();
}

/*
a detatched thread, that may be reused, to process data
*/
void threaded_worker_function(void *data_structure)
{
    while (1) {

        SSL_Mem_clean();

        /* process data_structure */
        some_process(data_structure);

        if (timed_signal_wait_for_new_data)
            continue;

        thread_release();
    }
}

/*
enable caller to pass new data to an unused/idle thread
*/
bool found_unused_idle_thread (data_structure)
{
    if (have_unused_thread) {

        assign_to_waiting_thread(data_structure);
        signal_waiting_thread_to_resume();
        SSL_Mem_clean();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/*
The primary function in a thread that may cause invocation of other functions requiring OpenSSL 
*/
void some_process(data_structure)
{
    /* calls various sub-routines */
    sub_routine();
    SSL_Mem_clean();
}

/*
a child function called that may use OpenSSL functions
*/
void sub_routine()
{
    /* calls further sub-routines, 
    each sub-routine calls SSL_Mem_clean()

    */

    SSL_Mem_clean();
}
```

Is there something I am missing? Or could have been better?

**Question:** Is SSL_thread_setup() being called from correct place? Should it be rather called after forking?

**Question:** Is the order of things in SSL_thread_setup() correct? Anything missing?

I am sure some of the good hacks here may discover the areas of improvement.

Thanks in advance.